# Autosmooth script fails in edit mode but works in object mode

Tags: python, scripting, operator

Here is a script I did to automate autosmooth and set the degree.
Pretty simple. It works in object mode great, however in edit mode it fails.
What I do not understand is why. It does not matter if I am in edit or object mode when I use the regular buttons in Blenders UI.

[image]

```
class SetAutoSmooth(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname ="set.autosmooth"
    bl_label ="Set Autosmooth"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
        bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = True
        bpy.context.object.data.auto_smooth_angle = 0.523599

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Here is the error I get. It states that context is incorrect.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Coding.blend\class Pie.py", line 14, in execute
>         File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\blender-2.76.0-git.d330162-AMD64\2.76\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in **call**
>           ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
>       RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth.poll() failed, context is incorrect
>
> location: :-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()` is only accessible from *Object Mode* (poll). To use it, you would have to toggle into *Object Mode* first. To shade in *Edit Mode* (using `ops`) you would have to use `bpy.ops.mesh.faces_shade_smooth()`. This will only work on selected faces though.

Comment: But then why does the interface button work when you are in edit mode? That is what I find confusing.

Comment: There is no Shade Smooth button in Edit mode's interface, only the shading buttons for faces, edges, and vertices in the shading/UV panel.

Comment: I am not talking about the shade smooth button - I am talking about the autosmooth button inside the buttons data menu. (image in the post). this one works in each mode!

Comment: But that is not the part of your code that is failing, its the line before that, as stated in the error report.